# Toolchain ABI identifier

Tags: c++, plugins, abi

I've created a plugin interface in C++ which relies on an abstract base class and C-linkage factories on each module, as shown below:

plugin.h:

```
class Plugin
{
    public:
        virtual uint8_t some_number ( void ) = 0;
};
```

plugin1.cpp:

```
class plugin1
{
    public:
        uint8_t some_number ( void ) override;
};

extern "C" Plugin *
    new_plugin
    ( void )
    {
        return new plugin1;
    }
```

Taking into account that there's no standard ABI, I'd like to check if a plugin is compatible *from the application*. For that purpose, two 8-bit integers are used to identify the interface version. However, that only solves the problem of adding or removing methods; it doesn't handle the case in which the application and the plugin are built with toolchains that follow different conventions.

Is there any method to encode an identifier of the ABI (i.e. a NULL-terminated character array defined at compile time)? Something like this:

```
/* defined by the compiler */
#define ABI "gnu-X.Y"

/* and then, in each plugin */
const char * plugin_abi = ABI;
```

As I haven't found anything, I suppose there's no standard way to do it, and that I'll have to handle it from the build system. **Anyway, is there any method to encode the toolchain ABI for later retrieving and identifying through dlsym?**

Thanks!